# Quadratic function diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

I'm trying to figure out how the algorithm in Lax's Linear Algebra gives an invertible matrix, which is required for his proof that it is possible to diagonalize a real quadratic form.

He gives it explicitly for the $i=1$ term.  Given a quadratic form $q(y)=(y,Hy)$ suppose that $h_{11}\ne0$, then
$$z_1=y_1+h_{11}^{-1}\sum_n^2h_{1j}y_j$$
and you are left with a quadratic $q_2(y)$ which only depends on all the components $y_2,y_3,\dots,y_n$ of $y$.  Using this method it should be able to change variables such that
$$q(L^{-1}z)=\sum_1^nd_iz_i^2$$
However, I tried this on a $2\times2$ matrix
$$H=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1/2\\
-1/2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$$
corresponding to $2y_1^2+3y_2^2-y_1y_2$.  According to his algorithm, I've found the new coordinates to be
\begin{align*}
z_1&=y_1-\frac{1}{4}y_2\\
z_2&=y_2
\end{align*}
However, the corresponding matrix to this change in basis does not diagonalise $H$ (i.e. $LHL^{-1}$ is not diagonal).

Would there be a simple ($3\times3$ or less) system that this method works on that I can try?  I'm also not entirely clear either why the corresponding matrix is immediately invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm does not yield a diagonalizing matrix $L$. Rather it yields a matrix $L$ such that $H = L^TDL$ where $L$ is the matrix such that $\mathbf{z} = L\mathbf{y}$. In your example

$$ L = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1/4 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$

And you can verify that for $D = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 23/8\end{array}\right]$ we have $H = L^TDL$.

In general you have a quadratic form $Q_H(\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{y}^TH\mathbf{y}$ and you're trying to find a diagonal quadratic form $Q_D(\mathbf{z}) = \mathbf{z^T}D\mathbf{z}$ and a transformation matrix $L$ such that $Q_H(\mathbf{y}) = Q_D(L\mathbf{y})$ or in other words $\mathbf{y}^TH\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{y}^TL^TDL\mathbf{y}$. So really what you're looking for is an $L$ such that $H = L^TDL$ not an $L$ such that $H = L^{-1}DL$.